# Weird shadow in iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have this weird shadow on the bottom of the screen. The background should normaly be complitly white. The shadow is only visible on this form, as far as I can tell, and only on iOS. If I scroll a little the shadow disappears.

[image: Shadow]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please provide more info, what are you expecting? What's wrong in this screenshot?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant view hierarchy of that area? Also any code related to those views if there is any. You must be missing something pretty obvious to have a big ass shadow right there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you didn't define a gradient background in the designer for the `ContentPane` or `Form` UIID's.